# Where are the docs for the `normalize` function that appears in Traefik docs?

Tags: traefik

[Traefik v2.10's documentation for the docker provider](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/#defaultrule) says the default rule is:

```
Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)
```

Where can I find the documentation for the `normalize` function?

It does not appear to be in the Traefik docs, nor the [Go template docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions), or the [sprig template docs](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was today looking for the same thing. Finally I came to this

https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/master/pkg/provider/configuration.go#L478

Explainig the function wouldn't fit here since I do not parse Go in my head.

I will desipher that with Go reference manual. Basic string operations.

Comment: Thank you!! My quick read of the code is that it replaces all non alphanumeric characters with hyphens